# logic for getting discounted price based on the mrp

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

[image: i want a code in c# for getting the discounted price. In the screenshot ,under product details we have RSP/MRP. So the requested price that needs to be entered should always be greater then or equal to 50% of RSP/MRP. i am using POM framework. so i need to create a page object for the shown page and apply the logic in the pageobject and call the method from my test class.]

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" rules="all" border="1" id="MainContent_gviewProduct" style="color:#333333;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <caption align="Top">
        <table width="100%" class="gridtitle"><tbody><tr><td class="text_Title">Product Details</td></tr></tbody></table>
</caption><tbody><tr style="color:White;background-color:#008D7A;font-weight:bold;">
        <th scope="col">Product Name</th><th scope="col">Product Code</th><th scope="col">Product UOM</th><th scope="col">Pack Size</th><th scope="col">RSP/MRP</th><th scope="col">Batch/MRP</th><th scope="col" style="width:150px;">Requested Price</th><th scope="col" style="width:150px;">Sale Qty in Packs</th><th scope="col" style="width:150px;">Remark</th>
    </tr><tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;">
        <td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gviewProduct_lblSelectedProdName_0">2T</span>
                    </td><td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gviewProduct_lblSelectedProdCode_0">1010068</span>
                    </td><td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gviewProduct_lblSelectedProdUOM_0">Ltr</span>
                    </td><td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gviewProduct_lblPackSize_0">210.00</span>
                    </td><td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gviewProduct_lblRSP_0">222.00</span>
                    </td><td>
                        <span id="MainContent_gviewProduct_lblBatchPrice_0">220.00</span>
                    </td><td>
                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gviewProduct$ctl02$txtRequestPrice" type="text" maxlength="10" id="MainContent_gviewProduct_txtRequestPrice_0" oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" onkeyup="return checkDec(this);" onkeypress="return funDecNum(event);" style="width:75px;">
                        <br>
                        <span id="MainContent_gviewProduct_rextxtRequestPrice_0" style="visibility:hidden;">Provide Valid Requested Price!</span>
                    </td><td>
                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gviewProduct$ctl02$txtRequestQty" type="text" maxlength="5" id="MainContent_gviewProduct_txtRequestQty_0" oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" onkeyup="return funOnlyNum(this);" onkeypress="return funOnlyNum(event);" style="width:75px;">
                        <br>
                        <span id="MainContent_gviewProduct_rextxtRequestQty_0" style="visibility:hidden;">Provide Valid Sale Qty!</span>
                    </td><td>
                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gviewProduct$ctl02$txtRemark" type="text" maxlength="50" id="MainContent_gviewProduct_txtRemark_0" oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" style="width:150px;">
                        <br>
                        <span id="MainContent_gviewProduct_rextxtRemark_0" style="visibility:hidden;">Provide proper Remarks</span>
                    </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

i want a code in c# for getting the discounted price. In the screenshot ,under product details we have RSP/MRP. So the requested price that needs to be entered should always be greater then or equal to 50% of RSP/MRP. i am using POM framework. so i need to create a page object for the shown page and apply the logic in the pageobject and call the method from my test class.

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481)

Comment: Didn't get you. this scenario can't be automated.

Comment: Show the HTML code of the `Product Details` table in your question with text, not in screenshot.

Comment: Edited the question with HTML code. Hope this would help.

Comment: I can't read that HTML in the format it's in. Please take a few minutes to reformat and clean it up (reduce it to only the relevant HTML). Where are your code attempts? I don't see them.

Comment: Edited the question with the required HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

While creating automation test cases you should not be creating a method for calculating the discount applied by your application or in fact any other business logic handled by the application.

Instead, you should have separate test cases with boundary values of prices and quantity for which you should know the expected values of discounts that will be applied.

If there is some change later in the logic for giving discount in your application then your test cases should fail as expected and then you will then update the expected result values in your test suite.

Comment: understood the logic. please guide me with the implementation of this logic in c# code format.

Comment: Tell me what have you tried so far related to this and where are you facing the problem?

Comment: i haven't tried anything as i am completely new to this kind of approach. so confused with how to start. so seeking for help.

Comment: @Hargovind are you saying you currently have no c# code?

Comment: @ Neil,Nope.. As of now the C# code which i have written will login into the application and navigate to the page given in the screenshot. Enter the details after which the product details will be displayed.